# C++ Need explaination on `static const WCHAR*`

Tags: c++

Making a Direct2D program, I want to convert from `int` to `WCHAR` so I wrote the following code

```
void DemoApp::OnRender() {

//...

int a = 256;
std::wstring wStr = std::to_wstring(a);
static const WCHAR* pStrNum = wStr.c_str();

//Print the number to the screen
_pRenderTarget->DrawText(
     pStrNum,
     sizeof(pStrNum)/sizeof(pStrNum[0]),
     _pTextFormat,
     rect,
     _pBrush);
//...
};
```

However, after one loop, the `pStrNum` changed to something weird, with the starting character is 5028 decimal base.

After messing a bit, I changed the conversion code to

```
const WCHAR* pStrNum = wStr.c_str();
```

The string printed almost correctly on the screen and everything seems to be normal except for the `sizeof(pStrNum)/sizeof(pStrNum[0])`  having the value of 2, therefore print only the first two characters on the screen.After all, I have to use `lstrlenW()` to get the number of elements in that string.

I need explaination on why `static const WCHAR*` is different from `const WCHAR*` and causes error

And why `sizeof()` doesn't work in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think (and I'll know for sure If I get lots of downvotes) that the behaviour of your code is *undefined*

This is because

```
static const WCHAR* pStrNum = wStr.c_str();
```

has `static` storage will be initialised once.

But wStr will be initialised every time the function is called, and that is the problem: in all subsequent calls to the function, the pointer will be dangling and the behaviour is undefined.

If I were you, I'd evaluate the .c_str() on a *just in time* basis. There will be no performance overhead in doing this.

To answer your question: use `wStr.size()` to get the length of the string: `sizeof()` returns the size of the data type (evaluated at compile time), not the string length.

Comment: I think it is undefined for a different reason: it will be initialized to hold a pointer to a local variable that dies after the function call. Since it is only initialized once, it holds a dangling pointer for the next calls.

Comment: This (the original answer) is simply wrong.  @juanchopanza has the correct analysis for this: because the variable is static, it is only initialized the first time the function is called.  (If this is his exact code, making `wStr` static would solve that as well.  But then, he might as well write `static wchar_t const pStrNum[] = L"256";` and be done with it.)

Comment: You're correct: I've amended. Didn't notice that the op had wrapped the code in a function.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(pStrNum)` gives you the size of `WCHAR*`, not the string it points to.

You can only calculate an array's length using `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` when you have access to the array declaration.  At other times, you need to pass a size along with the array or iterate over its elements until you find a sentinel element marking the end of the elements.  For a C-style string, you can iterate over its elements until you find one with value `\0`.  [wcslen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78zh94ax.aspx) does this for `wchar_t`.

```
_pRenderTarget->DrawText(
     pStrNum,
     wcslen(pStrNum),
     _pTextFormat,
     rect,
     _pBrush);
```

Or, simpler, as Kerrek SB suggests, remove all use of `pStrNum`

```
_pRenderTarget->DrawText(
     wStr.data(),
     wStr.size(),
     _pTextFormat,
     rect,
     _pBrush);
```

Comment: Why not simply `DrawText(wStr.data(), wStr.size(), ...)`?

Comment: @KerrekSB No reason other than me being slow.  I've noted this in my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` gives you the size of the object representation of whatever you pass it. You are giving `pStrNum` to `sizeof`, and `pStrNum` is a `const WCHAR*`, so what you're getting is the size of the *pointer*. `sizeof` doesn't work out the length of strings.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code doesn't work is that the compiler uses the static type of the variable to evaluate `sizeof`. `sizeof(pStrNum)` will  be either 4 or 8 bytes, depending on your OS, as the variable is a pointer.

Just rewrite the code as:

```
_pRenderTarget->DrawText(
     wStr.c_str(),
     wStr.length(),
     _pTextFormat,
     rect,
     _pBrush);
```

and you'll be ok